# Trying to upload zip file to azure storage via node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, azure-blob-storage

Trying to upload file to azure storage blob using nodejs but facing promise  issue. below is my code facing issue while uploading zip file to azure blob storage need to convert this code to callback function or .then function

```
var re = /\.zip/;

fs.readdir("/tmp/", function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
        console.log( "Could not list the directory.", err)
        process.exit( 1 )
    }
    console.log("files",files)
    
    var matches = files.filter( function(text) { return re.test(text) } )
    console.log("These are the files you have", matches)
    var numFiles = matches.length
    console.log(numFiles);

    if ( numFiles ) {
        // Read in the file, convert it to base64, store to S3

        for(let i = 0; i < numFiles; i++ ) {
    
          uploadFileToBlob(matches[i])
          .then((result: any) => {
              console.log('result');
              console.log(result);
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
})
const uploadFileToBlob = async (file: any) => {
          const { AbortController } = require("@azure/abort-controller");
          const { AnonymousCredential, BlobServiceClient, newPipeline } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
          const account = 'string';
          const accountSas = "sastoken";
          const localFilePath = file;
          const pipeline = newPipeline(new AnonymousCredential(), {
            // httpClient: MyHTTPClient, // A customized HTTP client implementing IHttpClient interface
            retryOptions: { maxTries: 4 }, // Retry options
            userAgentOptions: { userAgentPrefix: "AdvancedSample V1.0.0" }, // Customized telemetry string
            keepAliveOptions: {
              // Keep alive is enabled by default, disable keep alive by setting false
              enable: false
            }
          });
          const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
            `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net${accountSas}`,
            pipeline
          );
          const containerName = 'quickstart';
          const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
          const blobName = file;
          const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
          console.log("blockBlobClient",blockBlobClient);
          try {
                  const result =await  blockBlobClient.uploadFile(localFilePath, {
                    blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
                    concurrency: 20, // 20 concurrency
                    onProgress: (ev: any) => console.log(ev)
                  });
                  console.log("uploadFile succeeds");
                  return result;
                } catch (err) {
                  console.log(
                    `uploadFile failed, requestId - ${err.details.requestId}, statusCode - ${err.statusCode}, errorCode - ${err.details.errorCode}`
                  );
                  throw err;
                }
}
```

getting output

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

I tried to write code in callback function or .then function but getting same error and same code is working in local machine

Comment: Where are you getting this `Promise { <pending> }` output?

Comment: Inside console.log("uploadFile succeeds",blockBlobClient.uploadFile(localFilePath, {
              blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
              concurrency: 20, // 20 concurrency
              onProgress: (ev : any) => console.log(ev)
            }));

Answer (score 2):

Please change the following lines of code:

```
await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(localFilePath, {
  blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
  concurrency: 20, // 20 concurrency
  onProgress: (ev) => console.log(ev)
});
console.log("uploadFile succeeds");
```

to

```
const result = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(localFilePath, {
  blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
  concurrency: 20, // 20 concurrency
  onProgress: (ev) => console.log(ev)
});
console.log("uploadFile succeeds");
return result;
```

And then call your `uploadFileToBlob` method like:

```
uploadFileToBlob('filename.zip')
.then((result) => {
  console.log('result');
  console.log(result);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the complete code I used. I was able to upload the file successfully:

```
const uploadFileToBlob = async (file) => {
    const { AbortController } = require("@azure/abort-controller");
    const { AnonymousCredential, BlobServiceClient, newPipeline } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
    const account = 'account-name';
    const accountSas = '?sv=2020-04-08&ss=b&srt=sco&se=2021-03-08T18%3A30%3A00Z&sp=rwdxftlacup&sig=pT1d1NJQdu3bcnPA37voTCyQ6jKnmNVYgo1wyiYspDc%3D';
    const localFilePath = file;
    const pipeline = newPipeline(new AnonymousCredential(), {
      // httpClient: MyHTTPClient, // A customized HTTP client implementing IHttpClient interface
      retryOptions: { maxTries: 4 }, // Retry options
      userAgentOptions: { userAgentPrefix: "AdvancedSample V1.0.0" }, // Customized telemetry string
      keepAliveOptions: {
        // Keep alive is enabled by default, disable keep alive by setting false
        enable: false
      }
    });
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
      `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net${accountSas}`,
      pipeline
    );
    const containerName = 'container-name';
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    const blobName = file;
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
    console.log("blockBlobClient",blockBlobClient);
    try {
      const result = await blockBlobClient.uploadFile(localFilePath, {
        blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, // 4MB block size
        concurrency: 20, // 20 concurrency
        onProgress: (ev) => console.log(ev)
      });
      console.log("uploadFile succeeds");
      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(
        `uploadFile failed, requestId - ${err.details.requestId}, statusCode - ${err.statusCode}, errorCode - ${err.details.errorCode}`
      );
      throw err;
    }
}

uploadFileToBlob('filename.zip')
.then((result) => {
  console.log('result');
  console.log(result);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Did you remove the code for uploading from stream? You don't really need that.

Comment: Updated my answer with complete code I used.

Comment: I update question can you check with your approach and didn't work giving same error

Comment: I tried your updated code and it worked fine for me.

Comment: from local it is working but after deployment to aws lambda serverless then it is giving Promise { <pending> }

Comment: Aah...I see. Unfortunately I have no knowledge of AWS Lambda to further help you out :(. Please edit your question and remove `azure-functions` tag and add a tag for AWS Lambda for better visibility. Also include the fact that you're getting this error there only and not on local computer. HTH.